# Word that means "fashionable thinking of the day"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Help!
I forgot to write down a very useful word, all I've got are a few possible definitions from memory,

"fashionable thinking of the day"
"trendy idea / way of thinking"

The word is short, maybe 4 or 5 letters.

The word looks and sounds like "ersatz", using the "tz" sound I believe.

I've tried different anagram generators with no luck!
Same for Google, which thinks I want to read articles?

You're my only hope, what's the word?

Comment: I'd suggest https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist . *Zeitgeist* is a German word, meaning spirit of the age.

Comment: @rajah9 You should post as an answer. Seems like the right word to me.

Comment: Miles away from the "tz" sound, but there's a _smaller_ word: hip (the third definition [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hip))

Comment: The duplicate gives _zeitgeist_. Though 'vogue' would fit 'fashionable thinking of the day" ... 'trendy idea / way of thinking' better.

Comment: I agree that *vogue* might be better and meets the 4 or 5 letter requirement. But the tz sound requirement had me go for an ersatz synonym.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest *Zeitgeist*,  a German word, meaning spirit of the age.

> the defining spirit or mood of a particular period of history as shown by the ideas and beliefs of the time.
> "the story captured the zeitgeist of the late 1960s"

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeitgeist)  .

Here's a more extensive treatment from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist):

> The zeitgeist (German pronunciation /ˈtsaɪtɡaɪst/ ) is a concept from eighteenth- to nineteenth-century German philosophy, meaning "spirit of the age". It refers to an invisible agent or force dominating the characteristics of a given epoch in world history.

> Now the term is usually associated with Georg W.F. Hegel, contrasting with Hegel's use of Volksgeist "national spirit" and Weltgeist "world-spirit", but its coinage and popularization precedes Hegel, and is mostly due to Herder and Goethe. Other philosophers who were associated with such concepts include Spencer and Voltaire.

> Contemporary use of the term may, more pragmatically, refer to a schema of fashions or fads that prescribes what is considered to be acceptable or tasteful for an era, e.g. in the field of architecture.

While not a 4- or 5-letter word, it does have the t and z sounds. And it does encompass the fashionable thinking of the day.